# How to jump in Medal of Honor?

Tags: pc, medal-of-honor

I just started playing Medal of Honor today on my PC, and I started with the lowest mission, for "beginners." However, I get stuck a few minutes into it because I have to jump over barrels in a hallway. However, I can't figure out how to jump! I tried a bunch of different keys and nothing seemed to work.  Does anyone know?

Comment: I've never played this game, but most modern PC games have an option screen where you can customize your keys.  Whenever I get stuck with something like this, I look there to see if there's a button for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I've also never played the game, but in *every* FPS I've ever played where jumping was possible, it's defaulted to either space-bar or sometimes right-click.

Comment: @BlueRaja Ya it was the space bar. I've never played any non-sports games, so its new to me. Make an actual answer so I can accept it for you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never played the game, but jumping defaults to **<kbd>space bar</kbd>** (or sometimes right-click) in every FPS I've ever played.

Comment: So is it spacebar or rightclick?

Comment: @Eric > The comments above state that it is, in fact, the space bar.

Answer (score 1):

Err.. Press space?